# Errata to Analytical Methods in Economics by Akira Takayama

Tags: mathematical-economics, reference-request, textbooks

I found a mistake on page 312 and want to find out if there is an errata to this classic book somewhere.

As for the typographic error, the third equation in the footnote on page 312 should read:

$\frac{\partial \Gamma }{\partial x}=\pi u'(a_1)-p[\pi u'(a_1)+(1-\pi)u'(a_2)]\leqq 0$